# The loadRecord() method in modern version EXT JS 6.2.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern

From documentation **`6.2.0 EXTJS`**, the **`loadRecord()`** method is available only in the `classic` version. How can I replace it in the `modern` version? I want to get the following effect only in the `modern` version 6.2.0:

```
if (record) {
    me.dialog.down("forms").loadRecord(record);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setValues](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-setValues) function like this :

```
myForm.setValues(record);
```